# How do I request a frequency change to listen to ATIS?

Tags: safety, air-traffic-control, radio-communications, phraseology, atis

If I only have one radio, and I'm using VFR Flight Following, what do I tell ATC when I want to pick up ATIS for the landing airport before I'm told to contact the tower?

Comment: Not a true answer per se, but a lot of radios allow you to monitor the standby frequency. Check with your radio manual to see if this mode of operation is supported.

Comment: Isn't this part of why you're required to have two radios?

Comment: @Vikki  I'm not aware of any requirement that you have two radios. Many planes only have a single radio.   Can you cite a source?

Comment: You just ask.  "[Who you're calling], request a quick frequency change to get ATIS."  Works every time.

Answer (score 23):

Just tell them what you said in your question.

"Approach,  N23456 I will be off frequency for a couple of minutes to pick up the ATIS for ABC Airport."

That should work just fine. If the controller has an issue with that he/she will let you know and respond accordingly depending on existing circumstances.

Remember to report back on frequency.

Comment: As a controller, I appreciate the pilot phrasing it as a **request**, Otherwise I agree. The AIM doesn't specify phraseology so just use plain English.

Comment: @randomhead- I do understand and appreciate your comment.  Personally,  as a former controller I would take the suggested phraseology in my answer as an implied request.

Comment: I'd go with a shorter version:  *"Approach, N23456 request frequency change for ATIS"*, (wait for "request approved"). Then when you come back, *"N23456 now has Information Tango"*